# Read posts based on duration Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to archive some posts using - *Jekyll and Liquid* - based on the Month and Year Duration . My purpose is like this :

```
<h3> {{ month. year }} - {{month. next_year}} </h3>
```

...where the output will be like this:

> Oct. 2014 - Jan. 2015

I am new into jekyll/liquid and I don't understand much, tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
{% capture written_year %}'None'{% endcapture %}

{% capture written_next_year %}'None'{% endcapture %}

{% for post in site.posts %}  
  {% capture year %}{{ post.date | date: '%b.%Y' }}{% endcapture %}

  {% capture next_year %}{{ post.next.date | date: '%b.%Y' }}{% endcapture %}

  {% if year != written_year %}

    <h3> {{ year }} - {{next_year}} </h3>
    {% capture written_year %}{{ year }}{% endcapture %}

    {% capture written_next_year %}'None'{% endcapture %}
  {% endif %}
```

*Example Post:*

> http://prntscr.com/9cajee [Positions held is a < header > , IT User bla bla .. is the post title ]

Any tips/ documentation to read are welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to have `first post month year - last post month year`? Not very clear.

Comment: Basically I want to add my prof. experience so I want to add custom year duration , like on the example mentioned ! Is that possible?

Comment: Can you add an example post ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel I added one ! check it, hope it helps

Comment: I now found out that  Jekyll requires posts to be named year-month-day-title.md What i want is : year-month-day-year-month-day-title.md !! I think it's not possible right?

Comment: It's not possible to change post file name pattern. But you can change the permalink. Can you show one post file code, in order to see how is your front matter.

Comment: @User1911 you don't need to put the end date in the file name, you can put in the yaml front matter of your posts "end date: YYYY-MM-DD".

Comment: @Kpym Can you post me an example please ?

Comment: @Kpym @DavidJacquel
`---
layout: post
title: "Sample title"
excerpt: "Internship at . . . . "
tags: [sample post, code, highlighting]
end date: 2015-02-13
share: true
---` something like that??

Comment: @User1911 Yes, something like that. But probably with underscore in place of space `end_date` is better. Then you can access it with `{{post.end_date}}`.

Comment: DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMN :D YES!! That's it :-) Thank you soooooo much place it as an answer so I can vote it !